# Eclipse Error occurred during status handling

Tags: linux, eclipse, gtk

I used Eclipse IDE 2018-12 without any problem on my laptop running Manjaro Linux. After a while, which the things I did was updating my system.
I updated to Eclipse IDE 2019-03 with the hope that it will resolve my problem. I saw people with the same problem at stackoverflow adding WindowBuilder to .java, but that's not in my case. Here is my log:

```
!SESSION 2019-02-21 12:42:53.973 

-----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.10.0.I20181206-0815
java.version=1.8.0_202
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2019-02-21 12:43:14.772
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.
!SESSION 2019-03-23 21:00:12.584 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.11.0.I20190307-0500
java.version=1.8.0_212
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=ja_JP
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.core 1 0 2019-03-23 21:00:39.209
!MESSAGE Using Apache MINA sshd as ssh client.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2019-03-23 21:00:45.878
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4725)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4614)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4585)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawBackground(Control.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:6751)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6035)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.GTK._gtk_main_do_event(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.GTK.gtk_main_do_event(GTK.java:4135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.eventProc(Display.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_main_context_iteration(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_main_context_iteration(OS.java:1584)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4577)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1449)
```

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at the log, I understood that maybe either multilingual or non english or linux locale implementation is not supported by eclipse.

So, I reverted my system to English US and the Eclipse IDE works just fine now.